# The User Profile Service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded. Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

This started when my dad opened the laptop when the windows 7 was updating files on shut down. Not sure if it was finished cause i just left my laptop. then my dad opened it and im not sure what he did but it got into this weird desktop but it looks like winxp so i restarted.
Then the user proifile error showed up.

I googled for answers and it needs a win7 disk which i dont have. I cant boot into safe mode since it gets stuck on "please wait".

I tried running the built in recovery of samsung laptop and i run basic restore. but it just the same. And i think it made it worse since i cant see the user profile message anymore.

Comment: Did you ever find out WHY this was happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following methods to resolve this issue.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947215

Comment: Uhmm i cant follow those steps considering that i cant even boot into windows. So no "start" button.

Comment: ok, update! i CAN go into the safe mode with cmd! I can see the cmd right now. but theres no method for that

Answer (score 0):

Reboot windows to Safe Mode in Command Prompt and activate Administrator Account using the following command

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

Then reboot windows and modify regedit.